# Looking for equivalent of MinorTicks->None

Tags: plotting

I am looking for the *most general possible way* to suppress the display of minor ticks in Mathematica plots.<sup>1</sup>

More specifically, I'm looking for *the equivalent* (or *near-equivalent*) of a fictional `MinorTicks->None` option/setting (and its usual "partial variants", such as `MinorTicks->{None, Automatic}`, `MinorTicks->{Automatic, None}`, etc.).  This fictional option/setting is one that could be passed to any Mathematica function that accepts a `Ticks` option, and would have the sole effect of ensuring that the results do not include minor ticks along the element(s) indicated through the options argument (but may still include the usual major ticks, of course).

Note that I don't expect to get, literally, an implementation (somehow) of a `MinorTicks` option!  I'm looking for something *equivalent, or nearly so*, both in functionality and convenience.

(If this description of the question is clear enough, the remainder of the post may be safely skipped.)

---

I can imagine at least three possible ways to answer this question.  (But there may be other solutions I have not thought about!)

The simplest one, of course, if such an option already existed (e.g. maybe some obscure/undocumented variant of `Tick`, or some trick with the existing options that would have the net effect of suppressing minor ticks), would be just to post this information.  (This is the type of solution that strikes me as most likely, and, as it happens, for me also the most preferable.)

The second one would be if there were some *freely downloadable* package that implemented a similar functionality.

The third one (which I realize is highly implausible) would be to post, or point me to, a modification of the source code for Mathematica's function for generating ticks (or for a sufficiently close mimic of it) in which all the parts where all the minor-tick-generating code have been disabled.  (I realize that this may be too much work; it would suffice, however, just to point me to the source code of the function for producing the default ticks, and that I can use as the starting point for implementing a `noMinorTicks` function.)

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Just to be clear, I am interested only in solution that require only "standard" Mathematica (or possibly *freely available* add-on packages).</sub>

Comment: You might be interesting in the CustomTicks package from [LevelScheme](http://scidraw.nd.edu/levelscheme/)

Comment: @rcollyer  I saw the footnote *and* "The second one" (possible way to answer) in the body.  I'm misreading it, or there's a contradiction there.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I didn't notice the contradiction. Admonishment redacted.

Comment: Since you restated your requirements, ``LevelScheme` `` is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Presentations also has CustomTicks in which you can specify the number of minor ticks but it does not meet your requirement of freely downloadable. The problem of AbsoluteOptions (in one of the answers) not always reproducing the original ticks can often be solved by also specifying the associated PlotRange in the plot. However, there is also a problem with FrameTicks in that the rule will also eliminate all ticks on the top and right hand side. This could be solved by some extra programming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general form for the tick specification is

```
{x, label, len, style}
```

Minor ticks are easily identifiable: they have no label, or more correctly, the label is `""`. So, we can remove them from the tick specification in the `Graphics` object directly, if they were present. Unfortunately, in v9, they are often not included, so the internal algorithms take over.  You can see this by running

```
Options[
  Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 1}],
  Ticks
]
(* Ticks -> Automatic *)
```

The most straightforward way to acquire the list of ticks, then, is to use [`AbsoluteOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AbsoluteOptions.html), as follows:

```
Block[{plot = #, ticks}, 
 ticks =  AbsoluteOptions[plot, Ticks] /. 
     {_, "", {_, _}, {_, _}} :> Sequence[];
 plot /. Graphics[g_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :> 
     Graphics[g, ticks, opts]
] & @ Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Or, as pointed out in the comments, `Show` simplifies the code quite a bit:

```
Show[#, 
  AbsoluteOptions[#, Ticks] /. {_, "", {_, _}, {_, _}} :> Sequence[]
]& @ Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: +1 -- FYI `AbsoluteOptions` is not always entirely accurate and this may change the ticks relative to the original plot in unanticipated ways.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard you are absolutely correct, and I hesitated to post it because of that. But, when it does work, it is the _simplest_ method. I'll probably add something involving `FindDivisions` later, as it is more robust. Or, you could do it, as you need the points! :)

Comment: I'm curious: I would have used `Show[plot, ticks]` instead of `plot /. Graphics...` Any significant difference?

Comment: @MichaelE2 no, just habits die hard. I've been working with the raw objects a lot lately, and `Show` just didn't come to mind. Posted a simpler version.

Comment: Beware: Formatting your own custom ticks (from `FindDivisions`) is a headache.  Or at least I find handling the cases full of niggling pitfalls - I was going to post something, too, but it's not worth working out the details, given this solution and LevelScheme.

Comment: FYI, `AbsoluteOptions[plot, Ticks]` seems to be broken in V10 - at least in some cases such as above.  (I have the last beta, Mac OSX.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I believe that is on the list to fix, eventually.