# Remove minor ticks

Tags: ticks

I would like to remove minor ticks from my plots.

For example, consider the following code:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

which generates:

[image]

Is there any away to get rid of minor ticks and get something like:

[image]

I'm looking for a simpler solution than directly assigning numbers like this:

```
    Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Ticks -> {{0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10}, {-1, 1}}]
```

I found [this solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28994/looking-for-equivalent-of-minorticks-none). But this is also very complicated and seems outdated (it refers to very older version, 9, of mathematica).

Is there easier and updated solution?

Answer (score 8):

With version 10 you can proceed using undocumented functionality as follows (tested with version 10.4):

```
linearTicks = {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}][##, {20, 1}] &, 
   Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}][##, {2, 1}] &};

Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Ticks -> linearTicks]
```

> [image: plot]

Or shorter with identical result:

```
linearTicks = {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}][##, 20] &, 
   Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}][##, 2] &};

Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Ticks -> linearTicks]
```

> [image: plot]

Comment: thanks so much! I am implementing 10-20 plots with different scales. So does it mean that I have to write out twenty different `linearTicks` specifications? Can you please let me know what {20,1} and {2,1} mean? Once again, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @ppp The ``Charting`ScaledTicks`` function is undocumented but from my experiments the first digit means the maximum number of major ticks and the second number determines the number of intermediate minor ticks (between adjacent major ticks). And yes, in this way unfortunately you need to specify individual `linearTicks` for every plot AFAIK. It is a shame that *Mathematica* still has no built-n function without these shortcomings!

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Range](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Range.html),

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Ticks -> {Range[0, 10, 1]}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Ticks -> {Range[0, 10, 2]}]
```

[image]

and with Frame

```
f[x_] := x^2 - 5 x + 7

g[x_] := Sin[2 x - \[Pi]/3]

Plot[{
f[x]
, g[x]}
, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}
, FrameTicks -> {Range[-\[Pi], \[Pi], \[Pi]/4], Automatic}
, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

**Edit**

[FrameTicks](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks.html) is verry helpfull

```
Plot[{
f[x]
, g[x]}
, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}
, FrameTicks -> {Range[-\[Pi], \[Pi], \[Pi]/4], Range[0, 30, 5]}
, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

as well as [Ticks](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html)

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Ticks -> {Range[0, 10, 2], {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I like this solution. But minor ticks are still there on the vertical axis. Do you know how to remove them as well?

Comment: Is there any way to format {-1,1} for the vertical axis in the same way as that for the horizontal axis, i.e. {initial value, final value, incremental}?

Answer (score 6):

With versions greater than 10.1

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Ticks -> {Subdivide[10, 5], Subdivide[-1, 1, 1]}]
```

And

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4 \[Pi]}, Ticks -> {Subdivide[4 \[Pi], 6], Subdivide[-1., 1., 4]}]
```

[image: Sin plot]

Comment: Cool, I had not come across `Subdivide` yet. +1 for teaching me a new function!